# Why does this list comprehension only work on one list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
list2 = ["e","f","g","a"]
```

I want to make sure they don't have any element in common. If they do, I want to remove these elements from both lists. So in this example, "a" should be removed from both lists.

I tried using lists comprehensions:

```
list1 = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]
list2 = [x for x in list2 if x not in list1]
```

Printing the lists returns the following:

```
list1: ['b', 'c', 'd']
list2: ['e', 'f', 'g', 'a']
```

So it worked for list1, but not for list2... how come the list comprehension worked in one case, but not in the other?

Comment: Because you modified `list1`, before `list2` had a chance to run the list comprehension

Comment: well, you have delete the 'a' in `list1`, so it works. For instance try `list3 = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]` then `list2=...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `list1` is redefined with different elements after the first line:

```
list1 = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]
# ['b', 'c', 'd'] Different result, working with this now.
```

Just do it in-place on one line to fix it:

```
list1, list2 = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2], [x for x in list2 if x not in list1]
```

Comment: Sometimes I get confused by the most obvious things... didn't know you could define two lists in one line, thanks for showing me that!

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you don't *need* lists, a `set` is really nice here.

```
>>> list1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
>>> list2 = ["e","f","g","a"]
>>> s1 = set(list1)
>>> s2 = set(list2)
>>> s1 - s2
set(['c', 'b', 'd'])
>>> s2 - s1
set(['e', 'g', 'f'])
```

This will be much more efficient as the size the the inputs grow.  Note that you still need a temporary as you want the difference between `s2` and the *original* `s1`:

```
temps1 = s1 - s2
s2 = s2 - s1
s1 = temps1
```

(Or, as Alex points out you can use multiple assignment)

```
s1, s2 = s1 - s2, s2 - s1
```

Comment: And they can just be cast back to lists afterwards

Comment: @will -- Yeah, I've always wondered why that never made it into the stdlib next to OrderedDict ...

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing list1 with the result of the first list comprehension (["b", "c", "d"]) so "a" isn't in list1 anymore when the second list comprehension is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to **second list**,it will check with **filtered list1**.At that time **a** will be not present in **list1**,so it will print **a** in **list2**.You can use following code:

```
 list1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
 list2 = ["e","f","g","a"]
 list3=[]
 list4=[]
 for x in list1:
    if x not in list2:
       list3.append(x)
 for x in list2:
    if x not in list1:
       list4.append(x)
```

print list3
print list4

output:

```
   ['b', 'c', 'd']
   ['e', 'f', 'g']
```